# The meaning of "piled house-gear"

Tags: meaning

When he read Chinn’s note he laughed, which they deemed a lucky omen, till he called up policemen, who tethered the ponies and the bullocks by **the piled house-gear**, and laid stern hands upon three of that smiling band of the thieves of Mahadeo. The chaplain himself addressed them magisterially with a riding-whip. That was painful, but Jan Chinn had prophesied it. They submitted, but would not give up the written protection, fearing the jail. On their way back they met Mr. D. Fawne, who had heard about the robberies, and was not pleased.

This is from "The Tomb of His Ancestors" by Rudyard Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/TheDaysWork/ancestors.html

I can't understand the meaning of "the piled house-gear"
I am glad if someone would kindly teach  me.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I'm a native english speaker and I can currently only make guesses as to what it means.  This is text from over a hundred years ago.  Let me do some research real quick...

Comment: Presumably the contents of somebody's house which have been removed and stacked in a heap.